# Get the last occurrence of a string using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose my text is below:

> One of the compelling reasons for buying this phone could be its display. Of course, we would have loved full HD, but then again we shut up because of the punchy price-tag. The screen responsiveness is also good.

I just want to get the index of last occurrence of "the" string in my text.(using RegExp)

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b"+"the"+"\\b",'g');
var pos = re.lastIndex;
```

gives only the position of first occurence of the string `the`..
any suggestions?

Comment: Why overkilling it with regex? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp

Comment: FYI this has nothing to do jQuery, its vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Any idea how to do this using regex..??

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood what `lastIndex` means in your question.  `lastIndex` is used to set the start position for finding the next match when using `test()` or `exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way;

```
var pos = -1;
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null)
    pos = match.index;

alert("last match found at " + pos);
```

Comment: A regular expression is involved but not really committed. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need regex to find last occurence of substring . you can use native `.lastIndexOf()` method:

```
re.lastIndexOf("the");
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this using regex..??

Comment: @SashiKant: why are you making it complicated??

Comment: let it be complicated..
Cud u do it using regex

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression is `/\bthe\b(?!(.|\n)*\bthe\b)/` (no global flag!) ...meaning the word "the" which is not followed by the word "the".

To test:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + input + '\\b(?!(.|\\n)*\\b' + input + '\\b)');
var pos = re.test(str) ? re.exec(str).index : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution, even with non-global regular expresions:

```
    function regexLastIndexOf(str, regex) {
        regex = regex.global
            ? regex
            : new RegExp(regex.source, 'g' + (regex.ignoreCase ? 'i' : '') + (regex.multiLine ? 'm' : ''));
        var lastIndexOf = -1;   
        var nextStop = 0;
        var result;
        while ((result = regex.exec(str)) != null) {
            lastIndexOf = result.index;
            regex.lastIndex = ++nextStop;
        }
        return lastIndexOf;
    }
```